# SSRS (Report Builder / MS SQL 2016) - SSRS expression to combine results of two rows that are part of a group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

**Summary of report:**

I have created an SSRS report where the user selects a range of dates, and the report calculates Visitor Count and Visitor Over Capacity Counts for different Locations for each day in a range selected by users (each day displays in a separate column).  For instance on Nov 1, I have 30 visitors for Location B, but Location B's capacity is 16, so the Over Capacity Count is 14 for that day (30-16 = 14).

My report is grouped by date (for daily results) and location. Date is a column group.  Location is a row group.

**Here's my problem:**

In addition to the 5 locations that exist in the database, I also need to combine the results of two locations into a single row that behaves like the grouped locations (ie. results per day).  Since this combined location doesn't exist in the database as its own location, I had hoped to just add a row after the Location row group, but it comes up with 0 for results and doesn't display results per day like the groupings do.

If this worked as hoped, for October 31st, the "Combo Loc 3-4" Row would have DailyVisitorCount = 13, DailyOverCapacity Count = 6 (overcapacity is a count > 7)

**Report Layout**

The results are grouped by [date] (column grouping) and [location] (row grouping).  The COMBO LOC 4-5 in the example below is outside the row grouping.

[image]

***Current Results (for selected period of Oct 31 to Nov 02):***

NOTE: for the Combo Loc 3-4 I'm focusing on getting the daily visitor counts correct first (that's why the overcapacity count fields are empty right now).

[image]

***Desired Results***

[image]

**Expressions Used Successfully with Grouped Locations**

DailyVisitorCount (used for both DailyVisitorCount and TotalVisitorCount).

```
=Sum(Fields!VisitsCount.Value)
```

DailyOverCapacityCount (used for both DailyOverCapacityCount and TotalOverCapacityCount):

```
=SWITCH(
Fields!Location.Value = "LOC1" AND Fields!VisitsCount.Value > 24, SUM(Fields!VisitsCount.Value - 24), 
Fields!Location.Value = "LOC2" AND Fields!VisitsCount.Value > 16, SUM(Fields!VisitsCount.Value - 16), 
Fields!Location.Value = "LOC3" AND Fields!VisitsCount.Value > 7, SUM(Fields!VisitsCount.Value - 7), 
Fields!Location.Value = "LOC4" AND Fields!VisitsCount.Value > 7, SUM(Fields!VisitsCount.Value - 7),
Fields!Location.Value = "LOC5" AND Fields!VisitsCount.Value > 11, SUM(Fields!VisitsCount.Value - 11),  
   True, 0)
```

Averages were calculated by using the above expressions but adding to the end:

```
/CountDistinct(Fields!date.Value)
```

**Expression Used Unsuccessfully for combined location (outside grouped location row)**

```
=IIF(Fields!Location.Value = "LOC3" OR Fields!Location.Value = "LOC4", Sum(Fields!VisitsCount.Value), 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked to get the daily totals (still haven't been able to get the over capacity to work):

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Location.Value = "LOCATION3" OR Fields!Location.Value = "LOCATION4",Fields!VisitsCount.Value,0))
```